# Linux auto mount

Tags: linux

I have to auto mount the NTFS drives on Linux. The linux i am using is ubuntu. and is there any way to force mount the NTFS drives in case windows was not properly shutdown

Answer (score 2):

if you are using ntfs-3g, you can use -force option

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows -o force
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can the [/etc/fstab](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html) file.